# Kali Linux Vscode Python - Operation not permitted run python file with internal terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, permissions, vscode-debugger, kali-linux

Hy guys, i am trying to use vscode in kali linux.
But I ran into a problem.
The moment I start the python file from the play symbol in the terminal it gives me a permission error.

But if I boot from the terminal using `sudo python main.py` it works fine.

Would you know how to help me fix this problem?
i am used to launch with play, i find it annoying to type in the terminal every time.

[Screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZATv.png)

I also tried the solution found on the internet of `sudo code --user-data-dir = "~ / .vscode-root" my/path`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

the code to execute:

```
import socket
import struct 
import binascii

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0800))
while True:
    print (s.recvfrom(2048))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use :

```
sudo code
```

in the terminal

If it doesn't work try to remove it and install it again.